# How to convert the first header of a pandas dataframe to rows keeping the same ids

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel file whith two headers as follows:

```
ID           Jan              Feb          Mar
         A         B        A      B     A     B
1123     10        22      233     2     4     22     
1198      9         4       44    23    34     5     
101       3         6        3    43    33     34
```

when importing this xlsx in Pandas, it looks like bellow

```
     ID     Jan     Unnamed: 1   Feb     Unnamed: 2     Mar     Unnamed:3
              A         B          A         B            A          B 
    1123     10        22         233        2            4         22     
    1198      9         4         44        23           34          5     
    101       3         6          3        43           33         34
```

I want the output as follows in python

```
 ID      Date         A          B
1123      Jan        10         22          
1198      Jan         9          4       
 101      Jan         3          6  
1123      Feb       233          2
1198      Feb        44         23
 101      Feb         3         43
  .
  .
```

Comment: try ```pd.read_excel(file.xlsx,header=[0,1])```. This should give you a multiindex, from which you can safely stack to your desired format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) with `header=[0,1]` for `MultiIndex` and `ID` to index by `index_col` and the nreshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
pd.read_excel('file', header=[0,1], index_col=0).stack(0).reset_index()
```